# How to implement a single cycle CPU and avoid delay slot?

Tags: branch, cpu

I am implementing a single cycle (one instruction per cycle) CPU in verilog. The CPU should support RISC-V `add`, `lw`, `sw`, `beq` instructions.

The problem is, when the instruction `beq` is decoded, the instruction after `beq` has already been in the pipeline and will be executed, no matter what the comparison result is.

RISC-V specification says there should be no delay slots. How can I achieve that, without breaking the one instruction per cycle design rule?

Comment: One way is to treat all branches as predicted not taken, disabling writeback/commitment of the following instruction(s) and restarting fetch from the target address if the branch is taken. This is relatively simple but low performance. (By the way, "single cycle processor" typically refers to an unpipelined design, which would not have this issue.) Predecode on cache fill could reduce the branch detection and address computation latency; scanning ahead for branches is also possible; branch direction and  target prediction is another option.